# Align a sentance in a TextView of two lines

Tags: android

I have a textview which get text from server and that text is a full paragraph like and has a html format. Now i am using maxline=2 in xml to show some of the text in two lines. I have tried many tricks but nothing works. Here is my xml code, please tell me what going wrong with it?

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/subject"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/date"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

And this is how i set text into that textview.

```
message.setText(Html.fromHtml(details.Description()));
```

It always looks like this,

```
     This is the text
that came from server
```

As you can notice above where the first line start from the second on not starting from there below. I want both to start from same position. The problem is text coming from server is a single sentence and i can't use `"\n"` or `</br>` like tags and also this text is in the listview setting by getview. And i have also tried `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` and `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`

Comment: You could try settings `layout_width` to `match_parent` and then `gravity="center"` should work.

Comment: @Egor N that too not working

Comment: have you tried android:gravity="center|left";   ??